# How to access url mapping parameters within a constraint custom validation?

Tags: grails

In a grails 2.2.3 app I have the following url-mapping

```
import app.UserService

class UrlMappings {

    UserService userService

    static mappings = { ctx ->

        "/users/$id/records/$school/detail" {
            controller = 'user'
            action = 'recordsDetail'
            constraints {
                id matches: /\d+/
                school validator: { school, obj -> school in ctx.userService.getUserSchools(id) }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to implement a custom validation in school parameter. In order to do it I need to call userService.getUserSchools(id) method.

The current try give `java.lang.NullPointerException` with the message `Cannot get property 'id' on null object` I need to get access to `id` parameter within school custom validator. I tried `id` or `obj.id` but with no success.

Thanks for any advice

Comment: try obj.id or obj.params.id

Comment: Thanks for commenting but trying `obj?.params?.id` or `obj?.id` give me `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException` with the message `No such property: params|id for class: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.RegexUrlMapping`

Answer (score -1):

`obj` in this case is `RegexUrlMapping` which doen't allow to access `id` parameter, but you can use `org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder` to access any request parameters inside validator closure as follows:

```
RequestContextHolder.requestAttributes.params.id
```

or just:

```
RequestContextHolder.requestAttributes.id
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I am getting `params` as an empty map an `id` is null

Comment: This can't be used in  UrlMappings: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.